# RestAssured I miss one field when extracting Response Body from Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest-assured

I have got strange problem with RestAssured because I don't see one of the field.

when I use postman to send request

`curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/team/testing-endpoint'` 
as response I get:

`{ "timestamp": "2024-03-09T18:24:10.622+00:00", "status": 404, "error": "Not Found", "message": "UserName: userNameToDeletedoes not belong to team: teamName", "path": "/team/testing-endpoint" }`

when I use RestAssured:

`given() .get("team/testing-endpoint") .then().extract().response().asString();`

I get :

`{"timestamp":"2024-03-09T18:40:10.295+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/team/testing-endpoint"}`

Why I didn't get a field message in response in RestAssured?

For Testing Purpose I just created simple endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("testing-endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<?> testingEndpoint() {

   String userNameToDelete = "userNameToDelete";
   String teamName = "teamName";

   throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            "UserName: " + userNameToDelete +  "does not belong to teammmmm: " + teamName);
}
```

Thanks

I looked through google but found no answer.
I want to get access to "message" field by using RestAssured response